# Does Centos 6 and gnome support i7 hardware?

Tags: centos, gnome, intel-core-i7, laptop-display

I have installed Centos 6 on a new HP laptop HP PROBOOK 430G1. While booting I see the message

**Detected CPU model 6 family 69**
**unsupported hardware device : Intel CPU model**

Inspite of Centos installing successfully when the machine boots up there is no GUI just the command line. 
Seeing this I tried installing the gnome desktop using the command 
 yum install gnome*

This also installed properly but after rebooting, the machine still boots to the command line. After which I have to type the **startx** command to start the GUI. 
However this only works for the root user and not for any other user. 
Logging off the root user causes the machine to crash.
I have also tried changing the run levels but this just causes the machine to hang during boot up.

Even installing Centos as a virtual machine on the laptop gives the same problems.

My questions are these....

1. Is there any other solution to have the GUI start by itself during boot up ?
2. Is this a problem with Centos itself. As in the hardware is not supported ?
3. Or is this a problem with gnome. As in the hardware is not supported ?
4. Do I need to change any display settings ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check your installation disk for errors?  boot the ISO or disc and at the "boot:" prompt, type "linux mediacheck"

Comment: I have done that the media is fine

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite [FUBAR](https://www.google.com/search?q=FUBAR) to me.
As it looks like fresh installation I suggest to reinstall the system using graphical installer (to be sure the graphic hw is working properly).

Comment: The system always installs using the graphical installer. Any re-installation gives the exact same results